# Rotated picture looks like it's missing pixels

Tags: python, image, image-processing, matrix, python-imaging-library

I was playing around with PIL and transformation matrices to understand what's behind simple 2D image manipulation.

In my attempt to rotate an image as "low level" as possible (that is, not using any `rotate(degrees)` function, but doing the math) I decided to rotate every pixel of the image using a clockwise rotation matrix:

[image]

The rotation went fine, but the image now looks like it's missing some pixels.

Original image, painted on a 435x353 black background:

[image]

Rotated 45° clockwise and moved to the right by 300 pixels:

[image]

Oddly enough, the issue doesn't occur when rotating the picture 90° clockwise (and moving 400 px to the right):

[image]

What could be causing this? Using `Image.Image.rotate` works just fine, so I guess the issue resides on my code. It's worth mentioning the original picture has a transparent background, which was lost in the compression when uploaded here. However, I've done the exact same operation to a jpeg (non-transparent) image and the result was the same.

Code used to do the rotation:

```
import Image, ImageDraw
from scipy import misc
import math

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
W, H = 435, 353
im = Image.new('RGBA', (W, H), BLACK)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
bitmap = misc.imread('Image.png')

def affine_t(x, y, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    """Returns ((a, b), (c, d))*((x), (y)) + ((e), (f)).""" 
    return a*x + b*y + e, c*x + d*y + f

def crotate(x, y, r):
    """Rotate (x, y) clockwise by r radians."""
    # And move 300 px to the right for this example
    return affine_t(
        x, y, math.cos(-r), math.sin(-r), -math.sin(-r), math.cos(-r), 300, 0
    )

x, y = 0, 0
angle = math.pi/4
for row in bitmap:
    for pt in row:
        draw.point([crotate(x, y, angle),],fill=tuple(pt))
        x+= 1
    x = 0
    y += 1

im.save('out.png')
```

Comment: If you dive hard into Pillow you can see how it does it (mostly in C for speed; a moderately-sized image is easily a million-byte array)  Here's the [generic](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/c74738a964e56cb42f08ac35da081ec6e4c8ce84/libImaging/Geometry.c#L585) and [Affine transform](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/c74738a964e56cb42f08ac35da081ec6e4c8ce84/libImaging/Geometry.c#L777) (supposedly faster, I dunno the math) functions.

Comment: +1 for use of "orient" watch

Comment: You may find the warping functionality in skimage useful for experimentation: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_geometric.html#example-applications-plot-geometric-py The API of ``skimage.transform`` is documented here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/api/skimage.transform.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each destination pixel you need to calculate the source pixel, but NOT the vice versa. Due to roundings you have several source pixels mapped into the same destination pixel. That's why you cannot actually obtain good 45° rotation without interpolation. My suggestion is actually a nearest neighbour interpolation.

Comment: [Bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) between corresponding source pixels of each inversely-transformed destination pixel would give better looking results than simply using the nearest neighbor. This is illustrated in the Wikipedia article on [image scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28bitmap%29).

Comment: Even better for rotating and scaling is the [RotSprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RotSprite#RotSprite) algorithm.

Comment: RotSprite looks pretty elegant and efficient, thanks for the link.

Comment: I can recommend George Wolberg's book, Digital Image Warping, for learning more about the topic.  http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/diw.html

Comment: Can anyone explain me why those white pixels are not happening on canvas rotate api? Does it use interpolation implicitly?

Comment: Seems like it uses nearest neighbor or linear interpolation depending on CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled

Comment: So mapping from destination-to-source means nearest neighbor? I had the same problem but I resolved it by calculating rotation from target to source and picking pixels from source. So that is it nearest neighbor since when we round our sine & cosine calculations we get nearest index on source array. I just try to understand it completely.

Comment: Yes, whenever each pixel of your destination image is some pixel of the source image, no interpolation is actually done, and this is called "nearest neighbor". When you interpolate something, you can actually obtain colors that were not originally on the source image.